# jackson-module-scala serialize/deserialize Long keys in Map as Strings

Tags: json, scala, serialization, jackson, circe

Using jackson-module-Scala, I try to serialize and deserialize an object with an inner Map using a **Long as key**, but the Jackson serializes the key as String and doesn't deserialize it as Long ifgnoring the type efined in the Class.
Is it a BUG? Am I doing something wrong?

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.DefaultScalaModule
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.experimental.ScalaObjectMapper

case class InnerMap(map: Map[Long, Long])

object CrazyJackson {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val mapper = new ObjectMapper() with ScalaObjectMapper
    mapper.registerModule(DefaultScalaModule)

    val innerMap = InnerMap(Map(1L->1L))
    val serialized = mapper.writeValueAsString(innerMap)
    val newObj = mapper.readValue(serialized, classOf[InnerMap])
    println(serialized) // Why the key is serialized as a String?
    println(innerMap)
    println(newObj)
    assert(newObj == innerMap)
  }

}
```

The assert fails and the output of the println(serialized) statement is :

```
{"map":{"1":1}}
```

It is strange that printing newObj and innerMap is the same:

```
InnerMap(Map(1 -> 1))
InnerMap(Map(1 -> 1))
```

As @Varren says, the problem really is in the assert. But:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.DefaultScalaModule
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.experimental.ScalaObjectMapper
import org.scalatest.FunSuite

class CrazyJacksonTest extends FunSuite {
  test("test json comparision") {
    val mapper = new ObjectMapper() with ScalaObjectMapper
    mapper.registerModule(DefaultScalaModule)

    val innerMap = InnerMap(Map(1L->1L))
    val serialized = mapper.writeValueAsString(innerMap)
    val newObj = mapper.readValue(serialized, classOf[InnerMap])
    assert(newObj.map == innerMap.map)
  }
}
```

The assert result:

```
Map("1" -> 1) did not equal Map(1 -> 1)
ScalaTestFailureLocation: CrazyJacksonTest$$anonfun$1 at (CrazyJacksonTest.scala:17)
Expected :Map(1 -> 1)
Actual   :Map("1" -> 1)
```

I am lost! **The map must be a Map[Long,Long]**!

I must use this version because of Spark dependencies:

- Scala 2.11.11
- jackson-module-scala 2.6.5 and also test with version 2.9.1 with the same result.

Other info:

- Example: https://github.com/angelcervera/jackson-scala-map-bug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON allows key names to be strings only. [ECMA-404 The JSON Data Interchange Standard](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-404.pdf)

> An object structure is represented as a pair of curly bracket tokens
>   surrounding zero or more name/value pairs. **A name is a string.**

You are right and the assertion problem comes from Jackson.[image]
As you can see `classOf[InnerMap]` actually maps to `Map<Object, Object>` inside `InnerMap` but you have to submit typeinfo of this map to jackson to deserialize it correctly. It is explained in [this documentation](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-scala/wiki/FAQ#deserializing-optionint-and-other-primitive-challenges) and according to it you can just use

```
case class InnerMap(@JsonDeserialize(keyAs = classOf[java.lang.Long])
                    map: Map[Long, Long])
```

Comment: So the problem is with the assert. I thought that case classes implement equals and hashCode. In fact, why is "assert(InnerMap(Map(1L->1L)) == InnerMap(Map(1L->1L)))" ok?

Comment: Please, can you check my new example? I'm missing something. How is possible that the assert manage the inner object as Map[String, Long] if the case class is defined as Map[Long,Long]

Comment: The link to "How to compare objects for equality in Scala?" is a different case, because is comparing classes and not case classes.

Comment: @angelcervera yeah, sry, i was wrong and you are right that it comes from jackson and not from equals.  Updated my answer.

Comment: Magistral response! I understand now. I was looking for the documentation following the links in the README.md and all links are wrong. Now checking the wiki section. Thanks also for that.

Comment: "@JsonDeserialize(keyAs = classOf[Long])" also works!

Answer (score -1):

The Scala Jackson module does not infer the type of the key in the Map.
As @Varren responded, the solution is to annotate the model with Jackson annotations, but on this way:

- The model is tied to a specific parser (Jackson annotations in the model definition).
- The code is less clear.

So I decided to move from Jackson to [Circe](https://circe.github.io/circe/) and **remove annotations** to keep the code clean.
This is a test that proves that it is parsing and unparsing correctly:

```
  test("test json circe comparision") {

    import io.circe._
    import io.circe.generic.auto._
    import io.circe.parser._
    import io.circe.syntax._

    val innerMap = InnerMap(Map(1L -> 1L))

    val jsonStr = innerMap.asJson.noSpaces
    decode[InnerMap](jsonStr) match {
      case Right(innerMap2) => assert(innerMap2 == innerMap)
      case Left(error) => fail(error)
    }

  }
```

**It is not mean that this is the best solution for everybody.**
Circe has a plugin to use it in combination with Jackson parser, but I did not test it.